# Access host localhost from Kubernetes service

Tags: networking, kubernetes, localhost, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Kubernetes service (java application) that needs to access a database service on the host machine via http localhost:port

Is it possible to give the service access to the host machines network, and how?

Comment: Are you using kubernetes on **GKE** ? Where is installed your database then ? On one of your **GKE** nodes ? Somewhere outside your **kubernetes cluster** ? If it binds only to localhost address of the machine you won't be able to access it from anywhere else but this machine.